# SQL statement for unselected fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I've got a number of drop down lists, which allow the user to select values. The user can also choose to leave some drop downs unselected.

I'm attempting to construct an SQL statement which would show all results even if the drop down lists have not been used. I've tried the following, however no results are returned:

```
string field1 = null;
string field2 = null;

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ((@Field1 is null) OR (Field1=@Field1)) AND ((@Field2 is null) OR (Field2=@Field2))", connection))
    {
           command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Field1", field1));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Field2", field2));
    }
```

Could anyone suggest any ideas? Ive got too many drop downs to make an SQL statement for each unselected combination.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the value of 'Field1' and 'Field2' may be obtained from a drop down list. However, the user may not choose one if he desires. Thus, I'd like to cater the SQL statement for a general case, where if the user does not select anything, all the results would be displayed instead. This can be achieved by writing

> WHERE Gender=Gender

in SQL Server, but no results are returning when done through C#.

Comment: Are you sure the column Field1 has value "Field1" and Field2 has value "Field2" in the table you are selecting from?

Comment: They do not have those values, but I'm trying to display all the results in the table. When I write a query in SQL Server with that code, it acts as if it's ignoring the 'WHERE' clause, which is what I want in a case where the user does not select something from a drop down list.

Comment: your parameters are not named correctly, see Shark's answer below.

Comment: do not assign anything to variables Field1 or Field2 if user did not select anything.

Comment: @muratgu - updated my code to reflect the changes.

Comment: @muratgu It's actually returning the following error now:

The parameterized query '(@Field1 nvarchar(4000),@Field2 nvarchar(4000))SELECT * FROM C' expects the parameter '@Field1', which was not supplied.

Comment: Are you using a GridView to return the data to?  Is it possible you have CancelSelectOnNullParameter set to True?

Comment: @Andrew - I'm using a GridView, but the error is thrown when the command is executed, i.e. before the GridView is reached by the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Field1", field1));
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Field2", field2));
```

For SQL Server parameters you need to have the `"@"` sign in front of the parameter name when adding them.  See above for the corrected code.

**Edit**: it looks like from your edited question your query hitting the database might be a bit off.  If you are giving optional parameters, you need to be weary when adding them to your query.  This is probably more like what you want:

```
select *
from yourtable
where
    ((@Field1 is null) or (Field1 = @Field1)) and
    ((@Field2 is null) or (Field2 = @Field2))
```

Comment: Still returns no results I'm afraid!

Comment: @Sean Run a SQL Trace and see what query is hitting the database.  Hard telling without seeing your full query and your data that resides there.

Comment: @Sean: are you still assigning "Field1" and "Field2" values to your parameters? you should assign null if user did not pick anything.

Comment: @Sean muratgu is right.  If you are assigning just a blank text then it will still not be working.  Don't pass the new parameter if it's blank.

Comment: @Shark Updated my code to reflect the changes. Still not returning anything.

Comment: @Shark It's actually returning the following error now: The parameterized query '(@Field1 nvarchar(4000),@Field2 nvarchar(4000))SELECT * FROM C' expects the parameter '@Field1', which was not supplied.

Comment: Ended up using a different approach - but I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ( (@Field1 is null) or (Field1=@Field1)) AND ((@Field2 is null) or (Field2=@Field2))
```

Be sure to pass null in for those parameters where nothing was selected...

Comment: Updated my code to reflect the changes. Still not returning anything.

Comment: @sean: post what the actual query is.  Meaning, what values are you passing into it?  Also, are you sure there is data for the query.